# Server fetching old versions of images?

Tags: html, css, ftp

I uploaded new images to my server, but browsers are still receiving the old ones.  I say browsers (plural) because whether the computer has ever been to the site or not, whether caching is enabled or disabled, they are receiving the old version.  If I go to my FTP and download the file, however, it is the new one.  I have triple checked the extensions and the old versions do not exist anywhere in the directory they are being pulled from.

Am I missing something here?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Clear your cache if you haven't already and try deleting the old pictures off the server first and then upload the new ones again.

Comment: The cache isn't the problem obviously, since I said I tried different computers and disabling cache.  I'll try deleting the pictures instead of just replacing them though.

Comment: what about image name :-)

Comment: What happens if you completely remove the image from the server, is it still displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is caching the images, you need to add a random number or timestamp to the urls for the images. This will cause the client and server to think it is a different url, and will bypass the caching.

in jquery you can do something like

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
$('img').attr('src', 'image/path/image.jpg?'+rand);
```

making the img selector as specific as you need to catch the frequently changing images

If it is PHP generated code, you can add the random number on the server side

Comment: I actually just found the problem and it was serverside, but THIS my friend is a wonderful technique; I wasn't aware you could do that with images, and it will come in handy.  Thanks for the response!